# Error when Connecting to PostgreSQL from Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, oledb, delphi-7, postgresql-9.2

I want to learn how to work with ADO in Delphi. I am trying my hand at writing a Delphi 7 application which would simply connect to the database and run some queries. I am stuck at the 'connecting-to-the-database' part itself.

I am using Delphi 7 and PostgreSQL 9.2 as the database and my OS is Windows 7.

I downloaded the PostgreSQL OLE DB provider from [Here](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/oledb/) and registered it by following the instructions in the readme:

> INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS:
>   In order to install this software, copy PGOLEDB.DLL and LIBPQ.DLL into your system
>   directory. Next, as administrator, run "regsvr32 PGOLEDB.DLL". You should get a dialog
>   message saying "registration succeeded".

Then I tried to connect to the database as follows -

```
interface
const
    ConnectionString : string = 'Provider=PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider;Data Source=localhost;' +
                                'User ID=postgres;password=sd123;timeout=50000;';

implementation
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Connection.ConnectionString := ConnectionString;
    Connection.LoginPrompt := true;
    Connection.Connected := true;
end;
```

When I run the program, it doesn't show the login prompt. Instead, it gives the error '**Expected Authentication Request from server, but received -**'. I have tried to find the solution on the internet but didn't find anything. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL OLE DB driver is very old and unsupported.  Personally, I was never able to use it successfully.  Download and install the latest 32-bit ODBC driver from http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/ and use that instead.  With ADO in Delphi you'll need to use the OLE DB Driver for ODBC and configure that to use the PostgreSQL ODBC Driver, but everything can be configured through the connection dialog.